# How to test a function which calls async function using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jasmine

How to test this function:

```
var self = this;
self.someVariable = "initial value";
self.test = function() {
   self.functionWhichReturnsPromise().then(function() {
     self.someVariable = "new value";
   });
}
```

I have test case like below, I know it is wrong because before promise is resolved, the assert statement will be executed by jasmine:

```
it("should test the function test", function (done) {
    var abc = new ABC();
    abc.test();
    expect(abc.someVariable).toBe('new value');
});
```

Note that I do not want to use setTimeout() or any sleep methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things, you need your `test` function to `return` the Promise and you need to use an arrow function or `.bind` the callback to the parent function (otherwise the `this` in `this.someVariable` will refer to the callback function):

```
this.test = function() {
   return this.functionWhichReturnsPromise().then(() => {
     this.someVariable = "new value";
   });
}
```

or

```
this.test = function() {
   return this.functionWhichReturnsPromise().then(function() {
     this.someVariable = "new value";
   }.bind(this));
}
```

Then in your test you can do:

```
it("should test the function test", function (done) {
    var abc = new ABC();
    abc.test().then(function() {
       expect(abc.someVariable).toBe('new value');
       done();
    });
});
```

Comment: I have edited the question, so the only thing remaining is to return Promise from `test` function. Suppose that I cannot edit the `test` function to return promise, then is there a way still to test the variable `someVariable`?

Comment: If you can't return the Promise, then there is no way to accurately test this without a `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2):

You can just spy on the function which returns the promise.

```
describe('when test method', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.promiseResult = Math.random();
    spyOn(ABC.prototype, 'functionWhichReturnsPromise')
      .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(this.promiseResult));
  })

  it('then should change someVariable with the result of functionWhichReturnsPromise', function() {
    var abc = new ABC();
    abc.test();
    expect(abc.someVariable).toBe(this.promiseResult);
  });
});
```

No need to wait the promise, inside this unit test, you are not interested in how functionWhichReturnsPromise actually works, you only want to see that the result of calling functionWhichReturnsPromise will update someVariable value.

Have fun and luck

Answer (score 0):

Now `async` and `await` are available in jasmine. you can use them to test your async function weather its a promise or observable.

```
it("should test the function test", async (done) => {
    var abc = new ABC();
    abc.test();
    expect( await abc.someVariable).toBe('new value');  // await will wait until abc.someVariable resolved or rejected
});
```

I have been using `async` and `await` in my angular 4 application test and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've written two samples to show how to wait for the promise inside the test function.
**JavaScript**: https://codepen.io/zhangyanwei/pen/rNNXKaV

```
function trackPromise() {
  const P = Promise;
  Promise = function() {
    const p = new P(...arguments);
    Object.assign(this, p);
    Promise.recent = p;
  };
  Object.assign(Promise, P);
}
```

**TypeScript**: https://codepen.io/zhangyanwei/pen/ZEEgNNB

```
// Mixin interface, you could put it into *.d.ts file.
interface PromiseConstructor {
    recent: Promise<unknown>;
}

function trackPromise() {
  // Only overwrite the constructor
  const P = Promise;
  Promise = function<T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T> {
      const p = new P(executor);
      Promise.recent = p;
      return p;
  } as unknown as PromiseConstructor;
}
```